# как преобразовать. почему строки не выводятся?

Tags: php

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/php.xxx/1/arrays/foreach_ref.php on line 4
Call Stack
#
Time
Memory
Function
Location
1
0.0005
393408
{main}( )
.../foreach_ref.php:0
Array

<?php
$st = "4597219361|Thomas Anderson|1962-03-11|Текст, содержащий (|)!";
 $person = explode("|", $st, 4); // Мы знаем, что там только 4 поля.
echo "$person";
//$files = glob(".*.txt");
//echo "$files";
?>
```

Comment: echo не умеет печатать массивы. воспользуйтесь var_dump или выводите содержимое массива любым удобным способом

Answer (score 0):

```
$person = explode("|", $st, 4);
echo "$person";
```

$person - массив, а вы пытаетесь распечать, как текст.

для наглядности вызовите

```
print_r($person);
```

вместо

```
echo "$person";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$st = "4597219361|Thomas Anderson|1962-03-11|Текст, содержащий (|)!";
 $person = explode("|", $st, 4); // Мы знаем, что там только 4 поля. 
 foreach ($person as $k)
echo $k."<br>";
//$files = glob(".*.txt");
//echo "$files";
?>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
echo $person[0].$person[1].$person[2].$person[3];
?>
```